# Artifactory OSS throwing 405 Exception when running maven release:perform

Tags: maven, exception, pom.xml, artifactory, maven-release-plugin

`artifactory-oss-6.7.2` is throwing a `405 status code` exception when running maven release:perform

Created a `settings.xml` from artifactory "generate settings.xml" on repo.  All repos are virtual repos.  Added distributionManagement to my project pom file to use the ids for snapshots and releases from `settings.xml`.

**settings.xml:**

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
   <snapshots>
     <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
   <id>central</id>
   <name>libs-release</name>
   <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
   <snapshots />
   <id>snapshots</id>
   <name>libs-snapshot</name>
   <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
```

**myproject/pom.xml:**

```
     <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Artifactory Release Repo</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Artifactory Snapshot Repo</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

`run mvn release:perform output`:

> [INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project model: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.test:model:jar:0.1.0 from/to central (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release): Failed to transfer file http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release/com/srcrea/model/0.1.0/model-0.1.0.jar with status code 405 -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I followed something I found here -> http://forums.jfrog.org/Error-Code-405-with-mvn-deploy-td7174367.html

And updated DistributionManagement of the pom.xml

```
   <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Artifactory Release Repo</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/88888</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Artifactory Snapshot Repo</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/88888</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Re-Run and now I see it:

[image: artifactory repo]

But what is not clear is in order to generate settings.xml you need to associate virtual repos to a local repo.  Then generate settings off that and use the distributionManagement configuration to point back to the local repo.  What is the point of the virtual repo?